# simple make file using vpath is not working

Tags: c, makefile

i wrote simple makefile using vpath

```
COMMON_CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -DA2CSCC=0
CFLAGS = $(COMMON_CFLAGS) -I/usr/include/ -I./ -std=gnu99 -g

VPATH = ./test_app

CC: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./libs gcc

SRC: test.c

all: TARGET

TARGET:
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) -o test
```

It is giving undefined refrence to main.

When i give directly

> TARGET:
>
> ```
>        gcc test.c -o test
> ```

```
gcc  test.c TARGET
gcc: error: test.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: TARGET: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: i dont think we use = with vpath , the syntax is like "vpath tag-name path1"  .... try this and let me know if you still get error

Comment: Does test.c contain main function? What happens if you write `gcc ./test_app/test.c -o test` ?

Comment: @AlexFarber, yes that is working fine

Comment: if i write "gcc ./test_app/test.c -o test" is working, then how does i use vpath

Answer (score 3):

make will not go through your command and replace arbitrary strings with new versions based on VPATH.  If you want to use VPATH you *must* use automatic variables.  Only automatic variables will be reset.

This is all explained fairly clearly in the GNU make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes_002fSearch.html

You have various other problems in your makefile as well.  Change your rule like this:

```
all: test

test: $(SRC)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Just a note: creating a program named `test` is *never* a good idea.  That's a shell built-in and also a program in `/usr/bin`, and it just leads to confusion.  Use some other name such as `mytest` or similar.